# callback function not working visual studio extension c#

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, callback, visual-studio-extensions

in my extension development, i want to authenticate GItlab to get the accesstoken. I added my redirecturl (might be wrong - unable to find correct redirecturl). Gitlab browser was opening after if i click on authorize callback is not getting (any authorisation code). Please help me on this , im very new to extension development

```
string gitLabClientId = "237e8qwuidhdhjbadduiqwue8uq8wueu";
string redirectUri = "vs://pb.vsextension";
string authorizationEndpoint = "https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize";
string state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
string authorizationCode;

string authorizationUrl = $"{authorizationEndpoint}?client_id={gitLabClientId}&redirect_uri={redirectUri}&state={state}&response_type=code&scope=api+read_user";
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = authorizationUrl, UseShellExecute = true });

string accessToken = await ExchangeAuthorizationCodeForTokenAsync(authorizationCode, gitLabClientId, redirectUri).ConfigureAwait(true);

static async Task<string> ExchangeAuthorizationCodeForTokenAsync(string code, string clientId, string redirectUri)
{
    string gitLabTokenEndpoint = "https://gitlab.com/oauth/token";

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
                //new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "YOUR_GITLAB_CLIENT_SECRET"),
                //new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", redirectUri),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "refresh_token"),
            });

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(gitLabTokenEndpoint, content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); //ReadAsAsync<AuthenticationResponse>();
            return result;  //result.AccessToken;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"Token exchange failed. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried above code , im expecting like callback showuld work properly & access token i want to get it access token,

Comment: Your haphazard indenting makes your code harder to read than it needs to be. If you'd like strangers to volunteer their time to help you, you should make doing so as easy as possible. Please fix that formatting. VS should do it for you automatically so there's really no excuse not to.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Code format is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are not handling the callback to retrieve the authorization code. In the OAuth flow, after the user authorizes your application, GitLab redirects back to your specified redirect URI with the authorization code appended as a query parameter.

```
//Other variables ....

string authorizationUrl = $"{authorizationEndpoint}?client_id={gitLabClientId}&redirect_uri={redirectUri}&state={state}&response_type=code&scope=api+read_user";
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = authorizationUrl, UseShellExecute = true });

// Implement a callback mechanism to capture the authorization code
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add(redirectUri + "/");
listener.Start();

// Wait for the callback and extract the authorization code
HttpListenerContext context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
authorizationCode = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.Url.Query).Get("code");

// Close the listener once the authorization code is obtained
listener.Stop();

// Exchange authorization code for an access token
string accessToken = await ExchangeAuthorizationCodeForTokenAsync(authorizationCode, gitLabClientId, redirectUri).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

in this modification introduces an HttpListener to listen for the callback on the specified redirect URI. After the user authorizes the application on the GitLab site, GitLab will redirect to the specified redirectUri, and the HttpListener will capture the authorization code from the query parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in my extension im using RedirectUri is redirectUri = "vs://pb.vsextension"; Can you help me on this RedirectURi once again please

Comment: for using a custom scheme for a redirect URI, you need to ensure that your extension is registered to handle this URI scheme. Here are the steps you can follow:

Open your extension's manifest or configuration file.
Look for a section related to URI schemes or protocol handlers.
Add an entry for your custom scheme, in this case, vs.
For example:
`<Protocol Name="vs" DisplayName="Visual Studio Extension" />`
and then you should implement a mechanism to handle the URI scheme in your extension code.

Comment: `public void Initialize()
{
    // Other code..
    // set up a mechanism to handle URI 
    SomeEventManager.OnCustomSchemeActivated += HandleCustomSchemeActivation;
}
// Handle the activation of your custom scheme
private void HandleCustomSchemeActivation(string uri)
{
    string authorizationCode = ExtractAuthorizationCodeFromUri(uri);

    string accessToken = await ExchangeAuthorizationCodeForTokenAsync(authorizationCode, gitLabClientId, redirectUri).ConfigureAwait(true);

}
private string ExtractAuthorizationCodeFromUri(string uri)
{
    return authorizationCode;
}`

Comment: you've set the RedirectUri to "vs://pb.vsextension".
Actually  "vs://pb.vsextension" is a breakdown of:

vs: Visual Studio protocol scheme.
pb: Placeholder or initials for your extension.
َAlso you can try using a more traditional URI scheme or even an HTTP-based URI for testing. For example, you could use "http://localhost:1234" as the RedirectUri.

Comment: I hope it could help you.